# Transforming dataframe into some format

Tags: r

I have multiple csv. files in the following format

when opening as csv.
[image]

imported into R
[image]

I would like to transform the dataframe into the following format
[image]

Comment: Please follow community guidelines for R questions: “Please use minimal reproducible example(s) others can run using copy & paste. Show desired output. Use dput() for data & specify all non-base packages with library(). Don't embed pictures for data or code, use indented code blocks instead.” It would also be helpful to describe what you want rather than just “put it in this format” and leave it to us to puzzle out. That said, try `tidyr::separate_rows()`.

Answer (score 3):

Its ideal to also share some dummy data so that its easier for us to respond.

**tidyr** option using **separate_rows()**

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  tidyr::separate_rows(tenant_id,sep=" ") # assuming the separator is a space
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it would be nice if you can use the data, but you can use something like that.

```
library(stringr)
df = data.frame(property_type = c(1,2,3),
                tenant_id = c('1 1 1 1 1', '2 2 2 2', '3 3 3'))

df = data.frame(do.call(rbind, with(
  df, mapply(\(p, t) cbind(p, str_split(t, ' ')[[1]]), property_type, tenant_id)
)))
colnames(df) = c('property_type', 'tenant_id')
df
```